# MySQL Amazon RDS Load Times - Slow load on only one development instance

Tags: c++, mysql, amazon-web-services, networking, cgi

I have a MySQL server running on AWS RDS, and am using a C++ connector to connect to it (I am writing a cgi application). Connecting to this server is all fine and extremely fast through an EC2 Instance (on the same VPC), my colleagues local machine (on a different network publicly accessible over the internet) and my own machine using MySQL Workbench.

The problem arises when I try to perform multiple selects on a single page using the typical C++ connector code:

```
sql::Driver *driver;
sql::Connection *con;
sql::Statement *stmt;
sql::ResultSet *res;


driver = get_driver_instance();
con = driver->connect(BitQA::Database::HOST, // tcp://db.mysite.com:3306
                      BitQA::Database::USERNAME,
                      BitQA::Database::PASSWORD
                      );

con->setSchema(BitQA::Database::SCHEMA);

stmt = con->createStatement();


res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT questionTitle FROM tblQuestion WHERE id = '" + to_string(this->QuestionID) + "'");

while (res->next()) {
    title = res->getString("questionTitle");
}

delete res;
delete stmt;
delete con;
```

This exact code is all fine on all other machines / applications (listed above) but has an intense loading time of up to 30 seconds on my local machine running the cgi page (on apache).

Any idea what could be causing this would be appreciated.

Note: I have tried using the direct IP and a common connection object to reduce opening and closing connection (all produce same results)

Note II: `skip-name-resolve` is set to `OFF` but cannot be changed as RDS presents this data as read only.